# Transformation operator in Sequence of linear QND measurements

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, measurements, commutator, density-operator

I am following the book Braginsky and Khalili. Consider a measurement scheme where we connect a object to be measured to another quantum system which is then measured by classical devices.(Example: measurements of qubit states by coupling them to a resonator which is then coupled to transmission lines and amplifiers)

Then, after measurement, the the state of object is:
$$\hat\rho(\tilde q) = \frac{1}{w(\tilde q)} \hat\Omega(\tilde q)\hat\rho_{init}\hat\Omega^\dagger(\tilde q) \tag{3.25}$$
where $\tilde q$ is the observed output of measurement, $\hat\rho(\tilde q)$ is the final density operator of the object, $w(\tilde q)$ is the probability of getting $\tilde q$ in the measurement and $\hat\rho_{init}$ is the initial density operator.

If we consider only linear and QND measuremnts, $[\hat\Omega(\tilde q),\hat q] = 0$
$$\Rightarrow \hat\Omega(\tilde q) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|q>\Omega(\tilde q  -q)<q|dq \tag{5.6}$$
But then, using this result and the fact that:
$$[\hat q_j , \hat q_l] = ik_{jl} \tag{5.41}$$
(the $l$ and $j$ refer to $l^{th}$ and $j^{th}$ measurement operator)

the book derives the result: $$[\hat q_j , \hat \Omega_l] = \frac{\partial \Omega_l(\tilde q_l - \hat q_l)}{\partial \hat q_l}.ik_{jl} \tag{5.42}$$

My question is, how do I derive the last equation. I am unable to understand how will the position operator $\hat q_j$ act on eigen states of $\hat q_l$. Cause only then can I use eqn 5.6 in the commutation relation to move further along the calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using eqn 5.6, one can write:
$$\hat \Omega(\tilde q) = \Omega(\tilde q - \hat q)$$ where you replace every instance of q with the operator $\hat q$

Now, that would mean, $$[\hat q_j , \hat \Omega(\tilde q)] = [\hat q_j ,\Omega(\tilde q - \hat q) ]$$
But as $\Omega$  can be expanded as a polynomial in $\hat q$, and since commutation behaves the same way as differentiation when acting on product of operators, for example:
$$[\hat q_j,C\hat q_l \hat q_l\hat q_l] = C[\hat q_j,\hat q_l]\hat q_l\hat q_l + C\hat q_l[\hat q_j,\hat q_l]\hat q_l+C\hat q_l\hat q_l[\hat q_j,\hat q_l] = \frac{\partial C\hat q_l\hat q_l\hat q_l}{\partial \hat q_l}.[\hat q_j,\hat q_l]$$
Similarly, the above result follows.